# simple jQuery code for sticky navigation working in Chrome only?

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, navigation, sticky

I'm using this code to create a clone of the navigation (#nav-wrap) that slides in upon user scroll.

It works fine on Chrome but I just found out it doesn't in Firefox and IE10, I have no idea why though as no error is triggered, it just doesn't add the class 'down' to the body. Any idea why this could happen?

Here's the code:

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $nav = $(".nav-wrap"),
        $clone = $nav.before($nav.clone().addClass("clone"));

    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
        var fromTop = $("body").scrollTop();
        $('body').toggleClass("down", (fromTop > 200));
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.nav-wrap {
    position: relative;
    height: 80px;
}

.nav-wrap.clone {
    position: fixed;
        top: -80px;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
    transition: 0.2s top ease-in;
    z-index: 999;
}

body.down .nav-wrap.clone {
    top: 0; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XyVAG/193/

Thanks

Comment: How about some HTML example, so we can try it out? (or a JSFiddle)

Comment: Please show us a working example.

Comment: BTW, the problem is most likely due to the fact you are using 2 items with the same id. If you want to clone it, try it as a *class* - not an ID (otherwise you will end up with 2 elements with the same **id**, which is a no-no)

Comment: Thanks. I corrected it but it's not that it0s no-no for validation but I don't think this will prevent anything to work. I'll set up a jsfiddle and update the question

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XyVAG/193/

Comment: Firefox doesn't add the class 'down' to the body for some reason, while chrome does

Comment: Mmm it works for me in Firefox (not on fiddle, but a test page I created based on your fiddle). It also adds the **down** class fine for me according to Firebug.

Comment: But yet it doesn't on the jsfiddle..mmm weird. If I replace toggleClass() with addClass() it works. But then obviously the nav doesn't slide up anymore. I don't understand!